# For $T\in \mathcal L(V)$, we have $\text{adj}(T)T=(\det T)I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic $0$. For a linear operator $T\in \mathcal L(V)$, we know that $\bigwedge^n T=(\det T)I$, where $I:V\to V$ is the identity map.

Further, from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366845/is-there-a-way-to-think-of-the-adjugate-matrix-invariantly) answer we can define the **adjugate** of $T$ as $\bigwedge^{n-1}T^t:\bigwedge^{n-1}V^*\to \bigwedge^{n-1}V^*$, where $T^t$ is the transpose of $T$. We write $T^\sharp$ as a shorthand for $\bigwedge^{n-1}T^t$.

**The Question:** It is a well-known formula that if $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with entries from a field $F$, then 
$$\text{adj}(M)M=M(\text{adj}(M))=(\det M)I_n$$
where $\text{adj}(M)$ is the adjugate of $M$.

*I am trying to formulate this fact in the language of linear maps rather than matrices.*
The problem is that it does not mean anything to take the product of $T^\sharp$ with $T$. We just need to make a connection between $T^\sharp$ , $T$, and $\bigwedge^n T^t$.

Comment: These questions you've been asking are neat.  Is there a particular text you've been working through?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 
I am not following any book. Just that I have for sometime been thinking about exterior algebras. I came across exterior powers of vector spaces in a differential geometry course and realized that a lot of matrix facts can be said in a neat invariant way using this concept. I have always liked and searched for invariant and coordinate approaches whenever possible

Comment: correction: coordinate*free* approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's assume that $V$ has a non-degenerate bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ with a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ such that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta.  Let $*$ denote the Hodge star operator.  Note that we have the formula
$$ \langle x,y\rangle = *((*x)\wedge y) .$$

Let's identify any operator on $V$ with its matrix representation.  Then we have the following identity:
$$ \langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,T^T y\rangle \quad (x,y \in V) .$$
Now we extend $T$ to all of $\Lambda(V)$ in the standard way by the formula $T(x\wedge y) = Tx \wedge Ty$.  Then we have the identities
$$ \text{adj}(T)^T x = *(T(*x)) \quad (x \in V) ,$$
$$ \det(T) = *(T(*1)) ,$$
noting that $*1 = e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$.

Then for all $x,y \in V$, we have
$$ \langle \text{adj}(T)^T x,Ty\rangle = *(T(*x) \wedge Ty) = *(T((*x)\wedge y)) = \det(T) \langle x,y\rangle .$$
Since $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is non-degenerate, we have
$$ \det(T) I = (\text{adj}(T)^T)^T \cdot T = \text{adj}(T) \cdot T .$$

Comment: It is a bit unsatisfactory that we need to put an inner product structure. Do you know if a way which does not require an inner product?

Comment: I have been wondering if there is some kind of Hodge star operator that takes $\Lambda^{(k)}(V)$ to $\Lambda^{(n-k)}(V^*)$ without using an inner product.  I don't yet have an answer, and I have never seen anything like this before.

Comment: But also, once you have picked a basis, you no longer need the inner product structure, because you can define the star operation directly using the basis elements.  Also, if you want to define it over fields of characteristic greater than zero, it's not obvious to me what the inner product would even mean.

Comment: But now that I look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual, specifically at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Formal_definition_of_the_Hodge_star_of_k-vectors, I see that the definition requires a non-degenerate bilinear form.  So over the complex numbers, this would not be the standard inner product, which is sesqui-linear.

Comment: So instead, start with a basis, and make https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Computation_of_the_Hodge_star the definition.  And of course, once you have picked a basis, you also have a bilinear form for free.

Comment: There is a natural pairing of $\Lambda^k V^*$ and $\Lambda^k V$ defined by $\langle \phi^1\wedge\cdots\wedge \phi^k,\ v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k\rangle = \det[\phi^i(v_j)]$. I had a feeling that this pairing could be used to achieve the same things as done by the Hodge star. As for an operator that takes a member $X\in \Lambda^k V$ to a member $\Lambda^{n-k}V^*$, I can think of contracting a fixed volume form, say $\omega$, on $V$ by $X$. We would then have $\langle i_X\omega, Y\rangle = \langle \omega, X\wedge Y\rangle$ for all $Y\in \Lambda^{n-k} V$.

Comment: @caffeinemachine I think you should see if you can make it work.  Can you send me a message if it works out?  (My work is catching up to me, so I have to go and do other things.)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I have given below a proof that uses neither a basis nor an innter product (in case you are interested in this).

Answer (score 2):

I'll propose to you another (slightly different, but isomorphic) definition of the adjugate (classical adjoint). Im borrowing from section 8 of http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/27exterior.pdf .

Let $f:V\rightarrow V$ (with $n$ the dimension of $V$). We have a canonical isomorphism $\phi:V=\wedge^1 V\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(\wedge^{n-1} V,\wedge^n V)$ induced by the Wedge product. Let the adjugate $\mathrm{adj}(f):V\rightarrow V$ of $f$ be obtained from $\mathrm{Hom}(\wedge^{n-1} f,\wedge^{n} V)$ via $\phi$, i.e. $\phi\circ \mathrm{adj}(f)=\mathrm{Hom}(\wedge^{n-1} f,\wedge^{n} V)\circ\phi$. It is then easy to check that $\mathrm{adj}(f)\circ f=\det(f)\mathrm{id}_V$: simply check $\phi((\mathrm{adj}(f)\circ f)v)=\phi(\det(f)v)$ for every $v\in V$.

Comment: That's a slick idea!